# How to make tibbles display significant digits

Tags: r, tibble

I am working with data that has significant digits (i.e. digits after the "."). These digits appear when viewing my data both as a variable in base R, and also when the data is stored in a dataframe. However, they do not appear when I view the data in a tibble.

I need to view these significant digits for my work. Is there a way to make them appear when using tibbles?

Here is a reproducible example:

`x` has 5 significant digits, and 3 are displayed when using base R:

```
x = 1234.56789
x
[1] 1234.568
```

Within a data.frame, 3 significant digits are also displayed:

```
df = data.frame(x=x)
df
         x
1 1234.568
```

Within a tibble, though, 0 significant digits are displayed:

```
library(tibble)
df = tibble(x=x)
df
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      x
  <dbl>
1 1235.
```

Again, I am looking for a way to make more than 0 significant digits appear whening viewing my data in a tibble.

Here is the result of my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_1.4.2      readr_1.1.1       choroplethr_3.6.2
[4] acs_2.1.3         XML_3.98-1.12     stringr_1.3.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1          maps_3.3.0          splines_3.5.1      
 [4] Formula_1.2-3       assertthat_0.2.0    sp_1.3-1           
 [7] latticeExtra_0.6-28 yaml_2.2.0          pillar_1.3.0       
[10] backports_1.1.2     lattice_0.20-35     glue_1.3.0         
[13] uuid_0.1-2          digest_0.6.15       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[16] checkmate_1.8.5     colorspace_1.3-2    htmltools_0.3.6    
[19] Matrix_1.2-14       plyr_1.8.4          pkgconfig_2.0.1    
[22] WDI_2.5             purrr_0.2.5         scales_0.5.0       
[25] jpeg_0.1-8          tigris_0.7          ggmap_2.6.1        
[28] htmlTable_1.12      ggplot2_3.0.0       nnet_7.3-12        
[31] lazyeval_0.2.1      cli_1.0.0           proto_1.0.0        
[34] survival_2.42-6     RJSONIO_1.3-0       magrittr_1.5       
[37] crayon_1.3.4        maptools_0.9-2      fansi_0.2.3        
[40] foreign_0.8-71      class_7.3-14        tools_3.5.1        
[43] data.table_1.11.4   hms_0.4.2           geosphere_1.5-7    
[46] RgoogleMaps_1.4.2   munsell_0.5.0       cluster_2.0.7-1    
[49] bindrcpp_0.2.2      compiler_3.5.1      e1071_1.7-0        
[52] rlang_0.2.1         classInt_0.2-3      units_0.6-0        
[55] grid_3.5.1          rstudioapi_0.7      rjson_0.2.20       
[58] rappdirs_0.3.1      htmlwidgets_1.2     base64enc_0.1-3    
[61] gtable_0.2.0        curl_3.2            DBI_1.0.0          
[64] reshape2_1.4.3      R6_2.2.2            gridExtra_2.3      
[67] knitr_1.20          dplyr_0.7.6         rgdal_1.3-3        
[70] utf8_1.1.4          bindr_0.1.1         Hmisc_4.1-1        
[73] stringi_1.2.4       Rcpp_0.12.18        mapproj_1.2.6      
[76] sf_0.6-3            rpart_4.1-13        acepack_1.4.1      
[79] png_0.1-7           spData_0.2.9.0      tidyselect_0.2.4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can set the option `pillar.sigfig`

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 1)
as_tibble(iris)
# # A tibble: 150 x 5
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#  1           5.          4.           1.         0.2 setosa 
#  2           5.          3            1.         0.2 setosa 
#  3           5.          3.           1.         0.2 setosa 
#  4           5.          3.           2.         0.2 setosa 
#  5           5           4.           1.         0.2 setosa 
#  6           5.          4.           2.         0.4 setosa 
#  7           5.          3.           1.         0.3 setosa 
#  8           5           3.           2.         0.2 setosa 
#  9           4.          3.           1.         0.2 setosa 
# 10           5.          3.           2.         0.1 setosa 


options(pillar.sigfig = 7)
tb = tibble(x=x)
tb
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#            x
#        <dbl>
#   1 1234.568
```

See also:

```
?`tibble-options`
```

or online:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/tibble-options

Answer (score 1):

To see more significant digits when printing a tibble, a simple work-around is to use the print.data.frame() method:

```r
> df = tibble(year = c(2019.1482, 2019.7293, 2020.9826))
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 1
   year
  <dbl>
1 2019.
2 2020.
3 2021.
> df %>% print.data.frame()
      year
1 2019.148
2 2019.729
3 2020.983
```

It is a bit of a hack, but useful when you want to see extra significant digits only for some tibbles, and would prefer not to change the default value in pillar.sigfig.

Another alternative is to use the [`num()` function](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/num.html) to set column-specific formatting:

```r
> yearvec = c(2019.1482, 2019.7293, 2020.9826)
> df = tibble(year = num(yearvec, digits=4))
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 1
       year
  <num:.4!>
1 2019.1482
2 2019.7293
3 2020.9826
```

However note that currently (R version 4.3.0) the corresponding object type is not understood by some base-functions:

```r
> df %>% pull(year) %>% summary()
Error in `summary()`:
! `summary.pillar_num()` not implemented.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

See [Controlling display of numbers](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/numbers.html) for more details.