# How to turn off rounding when I knit to pdf or word doc?

Tags: r

guys so I am using a tidy model function to get the output of the RMSE and RSQ. I'm using the function as so and get the right output with the correct decimal places. My issue is when I knit to pdf it seems to round off my answer to the nearest 1 decimal place. Does anyone know how I can turn this off?

R code results.

[image]

When I knit to pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pillar.sigfig` option to [choose the number of significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621518/how-to-make-tibbles-display-significant-digits) a tibble prints (see `?tibble::formatting`). Then you can [set that option for a single code chunk](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#other-chunk-options) using `R.options`.

This gives:

````
```{r R.options=list(pillar.sigfig = 10)}

tibble::tibble(x=runif(5),
               y = runif(5))

```
````

Comment: Okay that worked! Awesome thank you so much! I have literally been searching for an answer everywhere. I even posted on other forums!