# Mutate across Rounding to two decimal places in R

Tags: r

When i do a computation across tables using mutate across it rounds to 2 decimal place. I want it rounded to 5. This is what i have:

```
mutate(across(A25:A1000, .names = "{.col}_Min") -
               across(A25_25min:A1000_25min)) %>%
```

How do I include a rounding to 5 decimal place?

Thanks!

Comment: `mutate` doesn't round, that's a `print` method artifact, the 16 digits are still there. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621628/8245406).